# Looking for a specific javascript input validation library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Not to sure if this is allowed here but the other day I came accross a javascript library (mainly for NodeJS I think) that allowed me to validate any variable for things like type, value, min, max etc. in the following style (not sure if exactly like so but I mainly remember the chaining):

```
if(insertLibraryNameHere(myNumberInput).int().min(0).max(10))
```

Im pretty sure the library itself implemented checks for TONS of other stuff as well such as strings etc.

Would anyone happen to know what Im talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for joi https://github.com/hapijs/joi

Comment: That looks extremely close to what I had in mind. Not exactly sure if its the same but I will go with this for now. Anyone with similiar projects may feel free to add

Comment: Have you seen that joi allows for schema validation?! Its super useful and powerful! I love it and use it in all of my projects